# Make Long Variable Return Decimal Answer in Java

Tags: java

How do you make Long return decimal?

```
long i = 10;
long g = 1028;

long gf =(long) i/ (long)g;

System.out.println(gf)
```

Current answer:

```
0
```

Desire Answer :

```
0.001 // round to 0.000
```

Comment: You can't, a `long` is integral by definition. You might use `double` instead.

Comment: err ... use `Double`?

Comment: `long` is `long int` actually, so no decimal would come

Comment: This would be nice to read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: sigh.. i have been trying for hours for nothing ain't..thank for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer arithmetic truncates fractional parts of a division. You need a `double`, and you need to cast an operand to `double` to create a floating point result:

```
double gf = (double) i / g;
```

The [JLS Section 4.2.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4) defines:

> If at least one of the operands to a numerical operator is of type double, then the operation is carried out using 64-bit floating-point arithmetic, and the result of the numerical operator is a value of type double. If the other operand is not a double, it is first widened ([§5.1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5)) to type double by numeric promotion ([§5.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
long i = 10;
long g = 1028;

double gf =  (double) i / (double) g;

System.out.println(gf);
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition a `long` is an integer.

However you can treat a long as a fixed-point decimal, just by dividing or multiplying wherever necessary. For example, let's say that `gf` is a count of the number of millionths.

```
long i = 10;
long g = 1028;

long gf = (100000 * i ) / g;

System.out.println(String.format("%d.%06d", gf / 1000000, gf % 1000000));
```

Alternatively, use a floating-point type like `float` or `double` -- always being aware of the risks caused by rounding errors.